# StructureMap.Mvc Setup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, structuremap

I am trying to use DI (structuremap) in my project but I get an error on setting up the DefaultRegistry.

This is the DefaultRegistry code:

```
public DefaultRegistry() {
        Scan(
            scan => {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
            });

        For(typeof(GenericRepository<>))
            .Use(typeof(GenericRepository<>))
            .Ctor<DbContext>().Is(new MyContext());
    }
```

The error is:

> cannot convert from 'myApp.Data.MyContext' to 'System.Linq.Expression>'

if I set the DefaultRegistry using:

```
For<DbContext>().Use<MyContext>();
```

I get this error:

> The type myApp.Data.MyContext cannot be used as type parameter 'TConcreteType' in the generic type or method 'CreatePluginFamilyExpression.Use()'. There is no implicit reference convesion from 'myApp.Data.MyContext' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'

and this is MyContext code:

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{

    public virtual DbSet<MyObject> Object { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyApp;Integrated Security=False;User ID=admin;Password=mypass;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
          //model binding code is here ...
    }
}
```